# Crash app when adding multiple activities android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello everybody I got an issue when I trying to run my app in my physical phone and just get crashed at run. its my 5 time making this app, when this happen just close at installing the app. I'm trying to make an app in the main activity two Image buttons and then open anther activity, each one, I checked myself without creating the image buttons. but when I putted the image button the app just get crashed.

here is my code.

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blurred"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blurbackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="97dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/backmain" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="Welcome!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_width="345dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Master all professions in the professions guide"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt4"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="348dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
    android:text="Be part of the game and be the master of professions, these guides are collected from users who offer great help in your adventure throughout Azeroth!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt7"
    android:layout_width="322dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:text="We have classroom guides available for you to master your character if you are fresh and new to the world of Warcraft, dominate your enemies and take the victory!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="227dp"
    android:layout_height="103dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="66dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alchem"
    tools:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buthorde"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/horde" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/butally"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buthorde"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ally" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butshow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:text="Show me!"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package hordemuzzle.wowprofessions;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button butonhorde;
private Button butonally;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/contm.ttf"));
    textView.setText("Welcome!");

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    textView1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/contm.ttf"));
    textView1.setText("Master all professions in the professions guide");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    butonally=(Button) findViewById(R.id.butally);
    butonally.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActally();
        }
    });
    butonhorde=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buthorde);
    butonhorde.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActhorde();
        }
    });

}
public void openActhorde(){
    Intent intenth = new Intent(this, Activityhorde.class);
    startActivity(intenth);
}
public  void openActally(){
    Intent intenta = new Intent(this, Activityally.class);
    startActivity(intenta);
}

}
```

**Logcat**

```
2018-11-01 23:30:05.204 1051-19358/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-11-01 23:30:05.204 1051-19358/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2018-11-01 23:30:05.291 1051-12094/system_process D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 4
2018-11-01 23:30:05.291 1051-4361/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{3382c8d u0 hordemuzzle.wowprofessions/hordemuzzle.wowprofessions.SplashScreenActivity}
2018-11-01 23:30:05.291 1051-12088/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process hordemuzzle.wowprofessions (pid 24362) has died
2018-11-01 23:30:05.291 1051-12088/system_process D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 24362
```

Splash screen activity

```
package hordemuzzle.wowprofessions;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen;

import static android.support.v4.os.LocaleListCompat.create;    

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    EasySplashScreen config = new EasySplashScreen(SplashScreenActivity.this)
            .withFullScreen()
            .withTargetActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .withSplashTimeOut(4000)
            .withBackgroundResource(android.R.color.background_dark)
            .withLogo(R.drawable.logo);


    View easysplashscreen = config.create();
    setContentView(easysplashscreen);


}
}
```

Comment: show your `SplashScreenActivity`

Comment: `butonhorde` and `butonally` are your `ImageButton` not `Button`. So you have a class cast exception.

Comment: Good Catch. @Piyush

Comment: @Piyush sheez thanx for help I'll take a look how declare the Image button propierty :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
package hordemuzzle.wowprofessions;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------    -------------------------
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/contm.ttf"));
    textView.setText("Welcome!");

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    textView1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/contm.ttf"));
    textView1.setText("Master all professions in the professions guide");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------




    ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.butally)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActally();
        }
    });
    ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buthorde)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openActhorde();
        }
    });

}
public void openActhorde(){
    Intent intenth = new Intent(this, Activityhorde.class);
    startActivity(intenth);
}
public  void openActally(){
    Intent intenta = new Intent(this, Activityally.class);
    startActivity(intenta);
}

}
```